# Python not replacing value as \\ being mapped with \

Tags: python, excel, replace, backslash

Any advice on how to handle python reading in \.

For example I have a maintained excel doc containing a single column of values eg.

A B C \D E

An issue I have in excel to start is that it reads \D as '\D which looks to be causing an issue when consumed into Python.

I'm reading these into a df and creating a list:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', sheetname='Data')
mylist = df1['Data'].tolist()

mylist
['A', 'B', 'C', '\\D', 'E']
```

How can I stop the '\D' being read in when I only want '\D'.

The aim is to then find any values in another data frame that match the list and replace them with ''. Any instance of \D is not replaced because \D is being mapped with \D. This is the really key point.

Thanks!

Comment: `'\\D'` is the [escaped](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringescapeseq) representation of the sting `\D`. Everything will be fine if you print the string, but not the list containing the string since this gives a technical representation.

Comment: In your code, you did not use `print` command to see the data.  `\\D` is the way python storing internally. 

Try `print(mylist[-2])` and `mylist[-2]` in your python terminal.

Here python is using extra \ to tell itself that there is \ char because simple \ is a special char in python like \n, \t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\\D'` is how string `'\D'` represented to distinct a `\`-character from an escape-sequence. You can verify that you have the proper data, e.g.:

```
>>> print(', '.join(str(s) for s in mylist))
'A, B, C, \D, E'
```